# Identification of ribbon sata cable

Tags: identification, hard-drive

I have a laptop with HDD. The cable connecting the HDD to the motherboard is torn and thus the HDD doesn't work. I was wondering if I will be able to do the replacement myself. The cable I am looking for is a ribbon sata cable (in [this document](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/g-series-15-5587-laptop_service-manual_en-us.pdf), on page 33 the cable with number 5 pointing at it).

My question is how can I find exact part I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it can be replaced without needing any special tools.

To find one search "Dell G15 drive cable" and look at the pictures.